# jQuery addclass and removeclass in order from child to parent and reverse

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, hover

I have a div (container) with inside another div (back)  and inside 2 divs (title and description)

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="back">
       <div class="title">text1</div>
       <div class="description">text2</div>
     </div>
</div>
```

On (container) hover I add a class to (back) and then to (description) and this its ok, but when I try to make the inverse sequence jquery remove and add again the classes to childs

```
$('.container').hover(function(){
        $(this).children('.back').addClass('back_hover').bind("transitionend webkitTransitionEnd oTransitionEnd MSTransitionEnd", function(){  <--  here I move (.back div) with css and wait for the transition end
            $(this).children('.descripcion').addClass('descripcion_hover'); <-- here I fadeIn (.description div) with css and wait for the transition end
        })
    }, function() {

    //  Here is the problem, I need to do the inverse secuence fadeOut the (descripcion) and then move back the (back) div.

        $(this).find('.descripcion').removeClass('descripcion_hover').bind("transitionend webkitTransitionEnd oTransitionEnd MSTransitionEnd", function(){
            $(this).find('.back').removeClass('back_hover');
        });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Diego After looking at your [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/diegomar/2422tL8z/2/)

**1.** your last line "$(this).find('.back').removeClass('back_over');" is missing a "h" in the class for "back_hover", and

**2.** this same line should be "$(this).**closest**('.back').removeClass('back_hover');"

**3.** finally, to answer why the description_hover was re-appearing, you needed to UNBIND the transition from the initial hover over.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.container').hover(function() {
        $(this).children('.back').addClass('back_hover').bind("transitionend webkitTransitionEnd oTransitionEnd MSTransitionEnd", function() {
  /* add the unbind here */
  $(this).unbind("transitionend webkitTransitionEnd oTransitionEnd MSTransitionEnd").children('.description').addClass('description_hover');
    })
}, function() {
    $(this).find('.description').removeClass('description_hover').bind("transitionend webkitTransitionEnd oTransitionEnd MSTransitionEnd", function() {
  /* replace .find('.back') with .closest('.back') */
  /* replace typo with .removeClass('back_over'); */
  $(this).closest('.back').removeClass('back_hover');
});
    });
});
```

See the forked update [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cpardon/n658ko4a/1/)

Comment: cpardon I edited the H (is only a trasncript error on copy on my production file its ok), I test with your line but dont works

https://jsfiddle.net/diegomar/2422tL8z/10/

Comment: the text come back

Comment: @Diego I can see you are new here. It is customary to up-vote someone that has helped your with your enquiry and answered your questions. Your question/problem is complicated due to many typos in your script samples.

Comment: thanks cpardon I voted positive to you and Nicky but I don't see my vote, say smothing like my reputation its too low?! :( 

your code is right, but on hover out the description_hover need to fadeOut before .back div initiate to move, to prevent text wrap.

Also I see the the .back div move back also when the mouse is over.

Comment: cpardon I think a got it..!!! here is the result.

https://jsfiddle.net/diegomar/2422tL8z/13/

Comment: thanks cpardon..!! the unbind solved the problem.. :)

Comment: Glad to hear. Tap the check mark beside this answer then :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.container').mouseover(function() {
    $(this).children('.back').addClass('back_hover').bind("transitionend webkitTransitionEnd oTransitionEnd MSTransitionEnd");
      $('.back_hover').mouseover(function(){
        $(this).find('.description').addClass('description_hover');
      }).mouseleave(function(){
        $(this).find('.description').removeClass('description_hover');
      });
  }).mouseleave(function() {
    $(this).find('.back').removeClass('back_hover').bind("transitionend webkitTransitionEnd oTransitionEnd MSTransitionEnd");
  });
});
</script>
```

Comment: please tell me if it don't work on your site. I'll help you check it :))

Comment: thank nicky but don't works. I have the jQuery library on my site.
and the hover works on hover but not on out.

Comment: I need to to do sequence in order. On hover I move the first child div and when this finish fadeIn the second child div and its ok until there.
But when I do the mouseout I need to remove the class from the second child to make the fadeOut and when this finish remove the class from the firt child to move the div back to the initial position

Comment: I create this 
https://jsfiddle.net/diegomar/2422tL8z/2/
maybe you can see better

Comment: i updated my code. I checked and it work good on https://jsfiddle.net/diegomar/2422tL8z/2/ . you can add my jquery and test it

Comment: @Diego your last line "$(this).closest('.back').removeClass('back_over');" is missing a "h" in the class for back_hover.

Comment: nick I updated the code with your code and add more text to show you which is the problem.
The problem is with the text wrap, this it the reason why I need the text appear only after the transition move finish.
I see that you put two mouseover. This make that if you are not over the the second child divs the text dont appear.

https://jsfiddle.net/diegomar/2422tL8z/8/

Comment: yes much better but the text continue to wrap because the description appear before the back div finish to move. And don't finish to despear before move back

Comment: Nicky I think a got it..!!! here is the result. thanks!!!

https://jsfiddle.net/diegomar/2422tL8z/13/

Comment: Sound great! :)